# Checkbox loading but not getting clicked HTML Angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Having a strange issue, checkbox getting loaded with id & values but not getting clicked. shows no error as well.

```
<button [popover]="columnConfigJobDetails"><span class="icon-cog"></span></button>  
    <popover-content #columnConfigJobDetails [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
        <ng-container *ngFor='let col of columnDropdownStates'><form>
            <label *ngIf='col' class="checkbox ">
                <input type="checkbox" id={{col.field}} [checked]="col.visible" 
                 name={{col.header}} (change)="onColumnChange($event)"/>
                <span class="checkbox__input"></span>
                <span class="checkbox__label">{{col.header}}</span>
            </label></form>
        </ng-container>
    </popover-content>
```

My Angular/typescript code looks like an array of objects.

```
this.columnDropdownStates -:

     0: {header: "Name", field: "name", visible: true}
     1: {header: "Devices Enabled", field: "enabledDeviceNumber", visible: true}
     2: {header: "Description", field: "description", visible: true}
```

New Update - I do get this error, not sure what it means though

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

Comment: Are you using a view child?

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala that's right.

Comment: How does `columnDropdownStates` prop gets created in your typescript file?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible fixes,

1. If you are initializing or assigning your `*ngIf` values on the `ngOnInit()` you have to move it to `ngAfterViewInit()` as at this point the change detection doesn’t work on the ngOnInit(). Another reason is, in most cases, your view is probably not initialized in the ngOnInit().
2. If you are using Angular version of above 8, you might have to set a static flag while creating your `@ViewChild` as it is mandatory from v8. For example,

   **@ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: }) templateRef : TemplateRef;**

The true or false values depends on the following situations,

`{ static: true }`    if you are accessing `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit`

`{ static: false }`    if you are accessing in `ngAfterViewInit`. This should also be used in your scenario where you are using `NgIf, NgFor, NgSwitch` or other structural directives.

**Note**: In Angular 9, the static flag is defaulted to false.

For more details please refer [this official discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810).